# Anonymous access on Sharepoint 2010, pages created using Visual Studio

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, anonymous-authentication

How do we make the pages what we created using Visual Studio inherit permissions?

They work fine when the person is signed on, but when they are anonymous, you cannot access the pages.

How do I get them to be visible for anonymous users?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that by saying

> pages what we created using Visual Studio

you mean application pages created in Visual Studio and deployed to _layouts directory. If you want to make such page anonymous, you have to change base class in your code behind. By default, application pages inherit from `LayoutsPageBase` class, and you have to change it to `UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase` and you have to override property `AllowAnonymousAccess`  to return true:

```
public partial class ApplicationPage1 : UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase
{
    protected override bool AllowAnonymousAccess 
    {     
        get
        {        
            return true;      
        }  
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Of course your web application also must have anonymous access enabled.

[Creating a SharePoint Application Page for Anonymous Access](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zwsong/archive/2010/04/29/creating-a-sharepoint-2010-application-page-for-anonymous-access.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Start at the web application and continue to the appropriate level. Here is the PowerShell commands. (I assume you can Bing for steps in the user interface.)

Web Application:

```
$wa = get-spwebapplication http://[your_url_here]
$zone = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUrlZone]::WhicheverApplies
$i = $wa.IisSettings[$zone]
$i.AllowAnonymous = $true
$wa.Update()
$wa.ProvisionGlobally()
```

Site:

```
$w = Get-SPWeb http://[your_url_here]
$w.AnonymousState = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb+AnonymousState]::On // or Enabled for lists & libraries only
$w.Update()
```

List:

```
$w = Get-SPWeb http://[your_url_here]
$l = $w.Lists["List_Name"]
$l.AnonymousPermMask64 = {BasePermissions as appropriate}
```

Comment: Is this different from adding anonymous access through Site Actions -> Site Permissions -> Anonymous Access?